# Animated series cartoon with good animation and a triangle artifact

Tags: story-identification, tv, cartoon, animated-series

The main character was something like a teen in age. His weapon was a triangle artifact with a yellow sphere in the middle that could change side and go purple.
The main character had something like a crew and they were the protectors of a huge white castle.

The villain's base was a giant black dragon that in one episode was close to dying and the bad guys needed to work together with the good guys.

I remember an episode were the artifact cloned the main character and made a villain clone that used the purple power of the artifact.  Also something about another dimension and some GIANT titans. (They kinda looked magic-mechanical style.)

Comment: Hi, welcome to SF&F.  Where and when did you see this?  Do you remember any character or place names?  Can you describe any of the characters?